# VS Code: Unable to debug Connexion/Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, connexion

I'm developing an API running on a Connexion-Flask app using Visual Studio Code. When started with `flask run` it works fine.

But when I'm trying to debug this app using the VS Code debugger I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\QT_Code\itk-demo-configdb\source\app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from connexion import FlaskApp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connexion'
```

The launch.json that I use for debugging is the following (which I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64243812/vs-code-how-to-debug-flask-app-that-uses-connexion) thread which asks a very similar question (but I can't make a comment there):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Connexion",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "connexion",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "./db_api",
                "--port",
                "8080"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

My app.py Is the following:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from connexion import FlaskApp
from .config import APIConfig


app = FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir='db_api/', options={"swagger_ui": True})
flask_app = app.app
flask_app.config.from_object(APIConfig)
db = SQLAlchemy(flask_app)
migrate = Migrate(flask_app, db)
app.add_api('db_openapi.yml')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080,debug=True)
```

I'm using the same virtual environment when starting via `flask run` and the debugger. So I don't understand why it says that there is no connexion module. Before I implemented Connexion the VS Code debugger worked fine, but now I can't seem to get it working.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody else has the same problem in the future.
This seems to be some kind of VS Code bug.

I tried starting my app via the command line and it did work. After that, I reinstalled all python packages in my VS Code venv (via my requirements.txt) but it didn't help.

Ultimately removing the virtual environment I used in VS code and making a new one solved my problem.